# Share data across Flask view functions

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask to build a very small one-page dynamic website. I want to share a list of variables and their values across functions without using a class.

I looked into Flask's `View` class, however I feel as if my application isn't large enough nor complex enough to implement a class-based version of my project using Flask. If I'm stating correctly I would also lose the ability to use the `route` decorator and would have to use its surrogate function `add_url_rule`.

Which would also force me to refactor my code into something such as this:

```
from flask.views import View
class ShowUsers(View):

def dispatch_request(self):
    users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('users.html', objects=users)

app.add_url_rule('/users/', view_func=ShowUsers.as_view('show_users'))
```

For variable sharing I thought of two techniques.

1. ```
   x = ""

   def foo():
       global x
       x = request.form["fizz"]

   def bar():
       # do something with x (readable)
       print(x)

   def baz():
       return someMadeupFunction(x)
   ```
2. ```
   def foo():
       x = request.form["fizz"]
       qux(someValue)

   def qux(i):
       menu = {
       key0: bar,
       key1: baz,
       }
       menu[i](x)

   def bar(x):
       # do something with x (readable)
       print(x)

   def baz(x):
       return someMadeupFunction(x)
   ```

Comment: Aside: there is no reason why a project needs to be "large" or "complex" before you consider using classes.

Comment: Very true, however this is my first project using the Flask API, and i'm teaching myself as I go. I hope to convert this to class base in the future however as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [application local `g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.g). According to the documentation

> Just store on this whatever you want.

It meets your needs here exactly.

```
from flask import g

def foo():
    g.x = request.form["fizz"]

def bar():
    # do something with x (readable)
    print(g.x)

def baz():
    return someMadeupFunction(g.x)
```